# Mental model for void* and void**?

Tags: c++, c, void-pointers

*Note:* I'm a experienced C++ programmer, so I don't need any pointer basics. It's just that I never worked with `void**` and have kind of a hard time getting my mental model adjusted to `void*` vs. `void**`. I am hoping someone can explain this in a good way, so that I can remember the semantics more easily.

Consider the following code: (compiles with e.g. VC++ 2005)

```
int main() {
  int obj = 42;
  void* ptr_to_obj = &obj;
  void* addr_of_ptr_to_obj = &ptr_to_obj;
  void** ptr_to_ptr_to_obj = &ptr_to_obj;
  void* another_addr = ptr_to_ptr_to_obj[0];
  // another_addr+1; // not allowed : 'void*' unknown size
  ptr_to_ptr_to_obj+1; // allowed
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles just fine with gcc 4.5.2, even the `another_addr+1;` part. Could you please add the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Philip: I recently stumbled over a posting that there is a GCC extension that allows to do arithmetic on void*. That's the reason why you do not get an error with GCC. The error message is already in the comment: 'void*' unknown size

Comment: thanks for clarification. Man do I hate those GNU folks...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`void*` is a pointer to something, but you don't know what. Because you don't know what it is, you don't know how much room it takes up, so you can't increment the pointer.

`void**` is a pointer to `void*`, so it's a pointer to a pointer. We know how much room pointers take up, so we can increment the `void**` pointer to point to the next pointer.

Comment: void* is a pointer to something, and you usually know *exactly* what that something is (e.g. a linked list of ints, referenced by void*), or you don't care (e.g. memcpy copies from void* to void*).

Comment: Probably one of the best explanations so far.

Comment: Ah.. Simply Amazing :) <3 it !!

Answer (score 7):

A `void*` points to an object whose type is unknown to the compiler.

A `void**` points to a variable which stores such a `void*`.

Answer (score 4):

A `void *` can point at *anything* (except functions).  So it can even point at pointers, so it can even point at other `void *` objects.

A `void **` is a pointer-to-`void *`, so it can *only* be used to point at `void *` objects.

Answer (score 1):

`void` is misleading because it sounds like `null`. However, it's better to think of `void` as an unspecified type. So a `void*` is pointer for an unspecified type, and a `void**` is a pointer to a pointer for an unspecified type.

Comment: "However, it's better to think of void as an unspecified type." great explanation in the context of `void*`, but should be explicitly qualified for that context as that's totally wrong for return types, argument lists etc..

Answer (score 1):

`void` is a type which has no objects.

`void *` is a conventional scalar type.

`void **` is also a conventional scalar type that happens to point to `void *`.

---

`void *` can be used to point to anything, but I prefer to use it only for uninitialized storage. There is usually a better alternative to pointing a `void *` at an actual object.

Comment: In C, `void *` is often the only practical way to implement "generic" functions.

Comment: @Oli: Yes, I guess I'm not sure of the language context here.

Comment: This is one strange mental model